# There has been or have been

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials

Which is correct:  I am concerned about whether there **has been** or **have been** any accidents.

Comment: *Is there any volunteers?* or *Are there any volunteers?*

Comment: It *has* to be ***have***, because ***any accidents*** is a plural NP. For reasons that aren't immediately obvious to me, it's not actually idiomatic to cast the whole thing into the singular and ask *whether there **has** been any **accident***. But if we change the specific noun, it's perfectly normal English to wonder whether [*there **has** been any **mistake***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there+has+been+any+mistake%22) (almost 3000 hits in Google Books).

Answer (score 4):

The correct forms of your query are

> I am concerned about whether there **has been** an accident.
>   I am concerned about whether there **have been** any accidents.

Both forms can **mean the same thing** since to ask about one accident (without specifying a specific accident or situation) is to ask about all accidents.

If you said

> **I'm asking about whether there was an accident.**
>   **Has there been an accident?**
>   **Was there an accident?**

You might get the reply

> **Yes, there have been several.**

Comment: In the same vein, *I have no problem with this answer* is effectively equivalent to plural *I have no **problems** with this answer*.